# Android: Extract data from ArrayList

Tags: java, android

I want to extract data from an `ArrayList`, but the LogCat shows null value.

My code is:

```
try {
   String sql = "SELECT Cname FROM demo";
   Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
   final ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
   while (rs.next()) {
      arrData.add(rs.getString("Cname").toString());
   }
   Campaign campaign_data[] = new Campaign[] {
      new Campaign(R.drawable.empty, "Today:"+ arrData.indexOf(0)),
      new Campaign(R.drawable.empty, "This Month:" + arrData.indexOf(1))
   };
} catch() {
}
```

Comment: Please add more details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is arrData of type ArrayList?

You seem to be calling indexOf(0) on it which is probably not what you want.

> #### public int indexOf(Object o)
>
> Returns the index of the first occurrence
>   of the specified element in this list, or -1 if this list does not
>   contain the element. More formally, returns the lowest index i such
>   that (o==null ? get(i)==null : o.equals(get(i))), or -1 if there is no
>   such index.

I would assume you meant to call get(i), so try the following:

```
      new Campaign(R.drawable.empty, "Today:"+ arrData.get(0)),
      new Campaign(R.drawable.empty, "This Month:" + arrData.get(1))
```